# How can I cast a enum string value to column type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to create a method that dynamically filters a model by a column. It needs to receive the column that I want to filter by (called `attr_name`), an `operator` as a string, and the `value` as a string.

I need to first cast the string value to the database column type so I can then do the sql query.

```
scope :filtered_by_attribute, (lambda do |attr_name, operator, value|
  comparing_value = Customer.attribute_types[attr_name].cast(value)
  casting_error = !value.nil? && comparing_value.nil?
  raise I18n.t('api.errors.unaplicable_customer_scope') if casting_error

  sql_query = sanitize_sql("#{attr_name} #{operator} ?")
  where(sql_query, comparing_value)
end)
```

The problem above is when it comes to `enums`. Enums are integers on the db but when I perform the casting it will return the same string value since for rails it is a string. Then, in the where query, it explodes since in the database it's comparing an integer column with a string.

Do you know how I cast a string value to match the type of a column in the database?

Thank you!

Comment: Show an example of calling the scope with enum attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cast` method casts a value from user input when it is assigned to an instance. In the case of `enum` when you assign a string value it remains a string value. It is converted to an integer only when it is persisted in DB.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: {confirmed: 1, cancelled: 2}
end

# this is where the `cast` method is called
@order.status = "cancelled"

# still a string since the `cast` method didn't do anything.
@order.status # => "cancelled"
```

What you really need is the `serialize` method. It casts a value from a ruby type to a type that the database knows how to understand.

```
Order.attribute_types["status"].serialize("cancelled") # => 2
```